# Convert integer value to float in RDB by adding trailing zeros

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to specify precision for integer value
I tried `cast(variable as DECIMAL(10, precision))` but it didn't help

Also is there a mask for specifying arbitrary length of integer part? The variable range is unknown

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for specifying mysql tag. I just wanted to draw more attention. I use Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
select format(x, 4)
```

In Oracle, you would do:

```
select to_char(x, '0.000')
```

For longer numbers:

```
select to_char(x, 'FM999999.0000')
```

Or perhaps:

```
select x || '.0000'
```

Comment: `to_char(x, '0.000')` gives me `######`.  This one `to_char(variable, '00.0000')` seems to work, but it looks like it is going to trim the integer part down to two digits, as well as append one leading zero in case if integer part consists of a single digit

Comment: using this: `to_char(x, '.000')` gives `######` again

Comment: does `FM999999` guarantee the masking of all possible integer lengths available for DB?

Comment: @mangusta . . . Up to 999,999.  You can add more 9s if you need.